# User Input not found in Database error message

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set up an error message for the console to print when the user inputs a value not found in the database. I believe the syntax should be printed within the `.fail(() => {` section. I know my logic should be; if assetTag is not in the database, console.log an error message. The issue I have is it still prints the GET request with each valued typed. I believe the Onkeyup is also an issue. Here is a screenshot of the console:
[image: console]

How can I get the error message to always display `Unable to locate ID in database` once the user inputs the first key until something valid is found, eliminating the numerous GET requests? Here is my Javascript:

```
const getAssetInfo = (assetTag, index) => {
    
    // get the table row that this input is in
    $.get("http://localhost:3000/assets/" + assetTag , (data) => {
      // find the `.description` element and set it's value 
      if (data){
        $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${index}`).val(data.serial_no);
        $(`#description${index}`).val(data.description);
        $(`#cost${index}`).val(data.cost);
        $(`#po_no${index}`).val(data.po_no);
      }
      
      console.log(data)
    })


    
      
    .fail(() => {
        if (`#asset_tag_no` != assetTag ){
            console.log('Unable to locate ID in database');
            
        $(`#manufacturer_serial_no${index}`).val("");
        $(`#description${index}`).val("");
        $(`#cost${index}`).val("");
        $(`#po_no${index}`).val("");
        }
    // });
   else {
    console.log('not enough characters to call API endpoint');
    };
  });

};

$('document').ready(() => {
    

    // Handler to Add New Asset
    const table = $("#formTable tbody");
    let count = 1;

    $('#add').click(() => {
        
        const newRow = `
        
                        
                    <tr index="${count}">
                    <form>
                    <td><input 
                    class="asset-tag" id='asset_tag_no${count}' type='text' 
                    onkeyup = "getAssetInfo(this.value,${count})";
                    
                    bottom required /></td> 
                    
                    <td><input  class="serial-no" id='manufacturer_serial_no${count}' type='text' bottom required readonly/></td>
                    <td><textarea class="description" id='description${count}' type='text' bottom required readonly description></textarea></td>
                    <td><input id='cost${count}' type='value' bottom require readonly/></td>
                    <td><input id='po_no${count}' type='text' bottom require readonly/></td>
                    <td><textarea id='remarks${count}' type='text' bottom remarks></textarea></td>
                    <td><button type="button" index="${count}" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove">X</button></td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
        `;

        table.append(newRow);
        // Handler to Remove New Asset
        $('.btn-remove').click(function(){
            let index = $(this).attr('index');
            $(`tr[index='${index}'`).remove();
        });

        count++;
    });
```

Comment: How do you want to check if the id is valid without making a get request per value? There is nothing in the code you've provided that would suggest it's possible

Comment: As above. What are you doing to check if it's valid?  Making a GET request.   Don't use the console to write end-user messages, it's a debugging tool.

Comment: If you don't want a 404 then have your `/assets/tag` URL return a true/false rather than 404.  If you're using REST then have a different url, eg `/assets/{tag}/check` (or similar) and when that returns true, use your full GET to get details.  put another way: `.fail()` should be used when something goes wrong, a valid search attempt is not "wrong" - you currently have no distinction between a valid search and something's broken (eg a 500)

Comment: @freedomn-m I was using the console for my coding purposes, I should have specified that it is not for the user. But I am unsure of how to check if it is valid, I might research try returning the true/false method listed above

Comment: I thought it a little odd.   You could then just ignore the 404s in the console.   But you can't get rid of the requests completely if your check is server-side.

Comment: You might also like to consider using `debounce` on the input event so that it's not on *every* keypress, but rather (eg) 250ms after the user stops typing.

Comment: @freedomn-m wait this is awesome! I think this is totally something I can use thank you